# Can you apply to scholarships during a gap year?

Tags: funding

I've decided to take a gap year because I cannot afford school. I'm going into my Junior year of undergrad after my gap. I plan on graduate school and want to be debt free. I've recently taken it upon myself to apply to a scholarship every week of this year. However, I'm starting to notice that they require students to be enrolled full-time. Does anyone have any insights on this? Will they just ignore it?

Comment: What sort of graduate degree are you seeking?  Possible duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/is-it-worth-self-funding-a-phd-to-attend-a-top-10-university

Comment: Typically scholarships require students to be full time *while they are getting the money* not when they are applying, but it could vary.

Comment: It will depend on the scholarship. There are many different patterns and rules. It ranges from automatic application by the school when you apply to the school up to requiring somebody in some council etc. to submit your name for consideration. Check with the admins of the scholarships you are concerned with, and the admins of the schools you are considering applying to.